# jQuery - select a container which has only more than certain amount of children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, each

I have some `div`s which all are siblings. Inside each div there are multiple images as direct children. I want to select `div`s which only has more than 5 images inside it, and append a `div` into it using jQuery.

My approach for this is as follows.

```
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
   <img>
   <img>
   <img>
   <img>
  <img>
   <img>
   <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
  <img>
   <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
```

jQuery snippet I wrote is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //var countimg = $(".main").find('img').length;
    var count2 = $(".main").children('img').length > 20;
    //console.log(countimg);
    //console.log(count2);
    if(count2 === true){
        //var i = 0;

        $.each($('.main img'), function (index, value) {             
            //i++;
            console.log('um inside'+i);
            //if(i > 10){
                $(this).css('display','block');
            //}else{
            //    $(this).css('display','block');
            // }

            return ( index !== "three" );
        });




        $.each($('.main img'), function (index, value) {   
                $(this).css('display','none');
        }
        $(this).parent().append("<a class='show-more'>See More</a>");
        }
});
```

Comment: you said 5 but code shows 20...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution helps even if you are not aware what your child elements going to be.

Here you have `<img>` but even in the case where container has different child elements, this below solution would work.

```js
let certainAmount = 5;
const $container = $('.main');

$container.each(function(){
  let $this = $(this);
  
  console.log($this.find('> *').length);
  
  if(($this.find('> *').length) > (certainAmount - 1) ) {
    //Selected and do something.
    $this.addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  padding: 5px;
  border:1px solid #a29e9e;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
.main.selected {
  background: green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
```

## Update: Append into Selected Container

```js
let certainAmount = 5;
const $container = $('.main');

$container.each(function(){
  let $this = $(this);
  
  console.log($this.find('> *').length);
  
  if(($this.find('> *').length) > (certainAmount - 1) ) {
    //Selected and do something.
    $this.addClass('selected').append("<button>Show More</button>");
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  padding: 5px;
  border:1px solid #a29e9e;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
.main.selected {
  background: green;
 }
 img {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to make this on page loads new contents each time ?

Comment: Yes totally possible. You can put above code into a function and call that function, as per your requirement. Your JS code that loads more content, could call the function that has above code at last.

Comment: i added another question can you please check it ?

Comment: Sure let me check.

Comment: @Faizal Munna, I hope you got the mail ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171740/discussion-between-faizal-munna-and-divy3993).

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way is to query by combining [.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/), [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and [> selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_parent_child.asp)

for e.g. , select `.main` with at least 5 direct `img` children

```
$('.main').has('>img:nth-child(5)');
```

for appending

```
$('.main').has('>img:nth-child(5)').append("<a class='show-more'>See More</a>");
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/tj48zgLf/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation in the question and the snippet you have written doesn't seem to match. However the following should do the needful.

```
$("div.main").each(function(){
    var imgCount = $(this).find("img").length;
  if(imgCount > 5){
    //Do what you wanna do
    console.log(imgCount);
  }
});
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9z3ot8a/) out.

Comment: can we select only the particular div using this code and append a div inside it ?

Comment: @FaizalMunna Yes you can by adding `$(this).append("<a class='show-more'>See More</a>");` inside the `if()` condition.

Comment: @NewToJS no if I add like this it will select all the div s

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code

```
$('.main:has(img:nth-of-type(5))').append('<a class="show-more">See More</a>');
```

:nth-of-type() selector, this would work only if the img elements are the direct children of the .main element